# TypeScript problem with types ErrorConstructor

Tags: typescript, types, constructor

I'm trying to create a function that takes ErrorConstructor and message and throws this error with a little bit transformed message. But I get an unexpected error when trying to pass custom error constructor that extends base error:

```js
err<E extends ErrorConstructor>(Err: E, message: any): never {
    throw new Err(`'${message}': at line ${this.line}, at column ${this.column}`)
}

class LexerError extends Error {name="LexerError"}

err(LexerError, 'Invalid token: ${some_token}') //here is the error
```

the error: `Argument of type 'typeof LexerError' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ErrorConstructor'. Type 'typeof LexerError' provides no match for the signature '(message?: string | undefined): Error'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type named `ErrorConstructor` is [defined in the TypeScript standard library](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/514d8d88416f9112acd94be07e95d62b8d957169/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L978-L982) as

```
interface ErrorConstructor {
    new(message?: string): Error; // construct signature
    (message?: string): Error; // call signature
    readonly prototype: Error;
}
```

So in order for something to be an `ErrorConstructor` it needs to not only be an actual constructor with a [construct signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#construct-signatures), it *also* needs to be a normal function with a [call signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#call-signatures) that returns an `Error` instance.  And your `LexerError` is only a constructor and not a normal function.

Since you only care about the construct signature, you should forget about the `ErrorConstructor` type and use the construct signature directly:

```
function err<E extends new (message?: string) => Error>(Err: E, message: any): never {
  throw new Err(
    `'${message}': minimal reproducible examples don't have unrelated errors`
  );
}
```

And you can verify that everything now works as expected:

```
class LexerError extends Error { name = "LexerError" }

err(LexerError, 'Invalid token: ${some_token}') // okay`
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.3#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAUwE6oDwFEUA8rJgAmAzomMgO6IAUAtsiSQIYDmyA-AFyIlSowwrAJSIAvAD5EWdHFQSaM1DywAaRAyZtkPZmACewnhQBuaRAG8AUIluIoAC1RxqFakpoADAOQASC5os7AC+3jx0gjB0zAA2iKjIAA7ORCAQMABGMch4zHSJ2WRECN5QiA7MZojgCTHMBEQosqgknsJWwVZWEHVMiAAyyLhoSnJ4BMRko6iW5Hk5YogARIPDqNNLiJ1WaKg0qyPN6t4AkmAmsTCNUHAA1oQ8-iRwDAD6N-dgoaIA9D+Id2Y+k8QA)